# My vscode doesn't work because of OneDrive any one know answer?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, onedrive

VSCode Version 1.52.1
OS Build : 19042.685
Version : 20H2

My vscode was working before i opened OneDrive. It doesn't work right now. I looked https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27285 but it didn't work on me. Also i tried File On-Demand but it didn't work on me too

Any one know the answer?

Comment: https://ibb.co/rdZPqwb This one is the error

Comment: Please update the question with the error in your comment, and describe the problem in detail. Also, this is a 'programming' site, not a 'fix-my-software-install' site.